# TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/ - in Django Tutorial

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-urls

I have been trying out Django tutorial(documentation) and is stuck with this error for 2 days now. I will paste my views.py, settings.py and my directory structure below. 
Views.Py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader

from polls.models import Poll

# Create your views here.

#def index(request):
    #return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You are at the poll index.")

def index(request):
    latest_poll_list = Poll.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'latest_poll_list': latest_poll_list,
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))

def detail(request,poll_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at the results of the poll %s." % poll_id)

def results(request, poll_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at the results of poll %s." % poll_id)

def vote(request,poll_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're voting on poll %s." % poll_id)
```

Settings.Py

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'ma_x5+pnvp$o7#5g#lb)0g$sa5ln%k(z#wcahwib4dngbbe9^='

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'C://Python34/mysite/db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Urls.Py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ex: /polls/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
)
```

This is the Error Traceback i get.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/

Django Version: 1.6.4
Python Version: 3.4.0
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'polls')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')

Template Loader Error:
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
C:\templates\polls\index.html (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\polls\index.html (File does not exist)
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\polls\index.html (File does not exist)
C:\Python34\mysite\polls\templates\polls\index.html (File does not exist)



Traceback:
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\mysite\polls\views.py" in index
  14.     template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in get_template
  138.     template, origin = find_template(template_name)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in find_template
  131.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/
Exception Value: polls/index.html
```

I believe the problem is with pointing my index.html file which is inside /mysite/polls/templates/polls/index.html. 
This is my file structure mysite/polls/templates/polls/index.html.

It will be a great help if someone can solve this problem. Any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did you comment `TEMPLATE_DIRS`? It's place where django will find your templates

Comment: Is the urls.py that you posted the main urls.py for the project or the urls.py from the polls app? relevant section of the tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/#write-your-first-view

Comment: @andrey :Sorry, i was trying out something else and so commented template_dirs. It was giving the same error even when i was using the template_dirs.

Comment: @shtuff.it :its polls urls.py. /mysite/polls/urls.py

Comment: The last location it looks at in the traceback is: C:\Python34\mysite\polls\templates\polls\index.html, that seems to match where you indicate the template is located, and yet it says  File does not exist. Does this path match where you placed your index.html?

Answer (score 4):

Please try replacing your TEMPLATES with the code block I've written below, copy it and replace your TEMPLATES:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['polls/templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [

            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
            'django.template.context_processors.media',
            'django.template.context_processors.static',
            'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I don't think your template_dirs=[] variable is working properly. If your on 1.9 then its depreciated and being over written/ignored. If your templates folder is in a different place then just write something crazy in there and look for it in the traceback, then compare that to your desired path and go from there...

hope this helped

Answer (score 1):

you should add your template directory to the `setting.py` file like this:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS=(
  "C:/python27/Lib/site-packages/django/bin/project1/templates",
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you have to do is create your polls folder, inside your template folder, as indicated in [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/3.0/intro/tutorial03/)

> Now we might be able to get away with putting our templates directly
>   in polls/templates (rather than creating another polls subdirectory),
>   but it would actually be a bad idea. Django will choose the first
>   template it finds whose name matches, and if you had a template with
>   the same name in a different application, Django would be unable to
>   distinguish between them. We need to be able to point Django at the
>   right one, and the best way to ensure this is by namespacing them.
>   That is, by putting those templates inside another directory named for
>   the application itself.

just like

[image]

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Use an absolute path when adding your template directory to `setting.py` this way:

```
'DIRS': ["C:\\Users\username\project\\templates"],
```